# Configuración Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, testing, pipeline, devops, jira

me gustaría saber si en Azure DevOps existe la posibilidad de crear una matriz de trazabilidad que me permita llevar un control al momento de ir agregando historias de usuario, por ejemplo:

Tengo un módulo de facturación, el cual contiene x número de historias de usuario; al intentar agregar nuevas historias de usuario me gustaría saber ese cambio que efectos puede tener, debido a que las historias de usuario es posible que estén relacionadas entre historias de usuario e incluso entre módulos, como en la tecnología todo es posible vengo a exponer este caso, si alguien tiene conocimiento agradezco me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

esto no responde a tu pregunta directamente pero te recomiendo que uses Cycle time y Lead Time esto lo puedes ver en tu dashboard.

**Cycle time (tiempo de ciclo):**

Mide el tiempo que tarda el equipo en realizar una tarea desde que comienza a trabajarla. incluye los tiempos activos de trabajo y los tiempos de espera.

**Lead time (tiempo de ejecución/entrega):**

Se refiere al tiempo que el equipo tarda en realizar una tarea desde que recibe una petición.

**Tiempo de ejecución frente al tiempo de ciclo**

El tiempo de espera se calcula a partir de la creación de elementos de trabajo para especificar un estado Completado. El tiempo del ciclo se calcula a partir de la primera entrada de una categoría de estado En curso o Resuelta para escribir una categoría de estado Completado.

**Identificación de problemas de proceso**

Revise el gráfico de control del equipo para ver los valores atípicos. Los valores atípicos suelen representar un problema de proceso subyacente. Por ejemplo, esperar demasiado tiempo para completar las revisiones de solicitud de incorporación de cambios o no resolver rápidamente una dependencia externa.
Como puede ver en el gráfico siguiente, que muestra varios valores atípicos, varios errores tardaron más tiempo en completarse que el promedio del equipo. Investigar por qué estos errores tardaron más tiempo pueden ayudar a descubrir problemas de proceso. Solucionar los problemas del proceso puede ayudar a reducir la desviación estándar del equipo y mejorar la previsibilidad del equipo.

Aquí tienen mas links que te pueden ayudar a buscar exactamente lo que precisas:

Ver y configurar un diagrama de flujo acumulativo:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cumulative-flow?view=azure-devops

Widgets de tiempo de plazo y tiempo de ciclo:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/report/dashboards/cycle-time-and-lead-time?view=azure-devops

Otros:

Configuración de un widget de evolución o evolución ascendente:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-burndown-burnup-widgets?source=recommendations&view=azure-devops

Gráficos de consultas de ejemplo:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/boards/queries/example-query-charts?view=azure-devops

Guía de evolución y evolución:

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/report/dashboards/burndown-guidance?view=azure-devops